# Printar somente palavras palíndromas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Treinando python, consegui fazer um programa que verifica se a entrada é uma palavra palíndroma. Segue:

```
def palindromo(texto):
    if len(texto) <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        return texto[0] == texto[len(texto) - 1] and palindromo(texto[1:len(texto) - 1])


linha = input()
while linha != "fim":
    linha = linha.replace(" ", "").upper()
    if palindromo(linha):
        print("é palíndomo")
    else:
        print("não é palíndromo")
    linha = input()
```

A entrada é, por exemplo:

```
Socorram me subi no onibus em Marrocos
5168615
osso
Caneta vermelha
A torre da derrota
04092016
fim
```

Que gera a seguinte saída:

```
é palíndromo
é palíndromo
é palíndromo
não é palíndromo
é palíndromo
não é palindromo
```

No programa acima, conforme a pessoa digita palavras que seja diferente de fim, ele verifica se é ou não palíndroma e printa a mensagem se é ou não.

Agora, gostaria que ter um programa que fosse capaz de ler um arquivo txt, com frases, e verificar quais das palavras são palíndromas e printar. Só que estou errando em alguma parte e não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar.
Poderiam me ajudar? Segue minha tentativa:

```
def palindromo(palavra):
    if len(palavra) <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        return palavra[0] == palavra[len(palavra) - 1] and palindromo(palavra[1:len(palavra) - 1])


def obtemPalavras(nomeArquivo):
    palavras = open(nomeArquivo, "r")
    for line in palavras:
        palavra = line.replace("\n", "")
        palavra = palavra.lower()
    return palavra


nomeArquivo = "palavras.txt"
palavra = obtemPalavras(nomeArquivo)
if palindromo(palavra):
    print (palavra)
```

Meu arquivo txt tem o seguinte conteúdo:

```
Hoje quem mais ama a anna é o chico
Amanhã de asa delta vai descer o Augusto
socorrammesubinoonibusemmarrocos
bob esponja
```

A saída que eu gostaria é:

```
ama
a
anna
é
o
asa
socorrammesubinoonibusemmarrocos
bob
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você está treinando Python vou postar minha resposta pra contribuir com seus estudos.

---

### Índices negativos

A primeira observação que tenho é que na sua função `palindromo` você "fatia" a string das seguintes maneiras:

```
palavra[len(palavra) - 1]  # pega a última letra da string
palavra[1:len(palavra) - 1]  # cópia da string sem o primeiro e último caracteres
```

Como string em Python são [sequências](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range), você pode usar índices negativos para acessar a sequência a partir de seu fim. Ou seja, você pode pegar a última letra de uma string buscando pelo índice `-1`, veja:

```
palavra = "abcde"
palavra[-1]  # "e"
```

O mesmo conceito pode ser usado ao fatiar uma sequência (veja [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice)):

```
palavra = "abcde"
palavra[1:-1]  # "bcd"
```

---

### Leitura de um arquivo

A segunda observação é uma recomendação, quando for ler algum arquivo utilize [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with), pois assim o objeto que faz a leitura do arquivo se encarrega de fechá-lo, mesmo que uma exceção seja lançada durante sua leitura. A mudança no seu código é mínima, veja:

**Antes**:

```
palavras = open(nomeArquivo, "r")

for line in palavras:
    # processa o texto

# você não liberou o arquivo para o sistema operacional (palavras.close())
return palavra
```

**Depois**:

```
with open(nomeArquivo, "r", encoding="utf8") as arquivo:
    for line in arquivo:
        # processa o texto

# arquivo.close() foi executado automaticamente
return palavra
```

---

### Retornar todas as palavras de um arquivo

Minha terceira observação é que na sua função `obtemPalavras`, você cria a variável `palavra` dentro do `for`, faz modificações em seu conteúdo e não guarda em lugar algum.

Dessa maneira a segunda execução do laço vai apagar o valor contido em `palavra` calculado na primeira execução, e a terceira apagará o valor da segunda, e assim por diante. No fim você está retornando apenas o resultado do último laço do `for`.

Você poderia guardar o resultado de cada um dos laços em uma lista e retorná-lo no final. Seu código ficaria assim:

```
palavras = []
for line in arquivo:
    palavra = line.replace("\n", "").lower().split()
    palavras += palavra
return palavras
```

O código acima quebra a linha em palavras utilizando o método [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) que retorna uma lista de strings, esta lista é então somada à lista `palavras` que guardará nossos resultados. Ao somar duas lista você está concatenando elas. O código abaixo ilustra isto:

```
lista = "1 2 3 4 5".split()
# ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

outra_lista = ['6', '7', '8']

# retorna um nova lista com as duas listas concatenadas
terceira_lista = lista + outra_lista
# ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']

# Concatena as duas lista e guarda o resultado dentro de `lista
lista = lista + outra_lista
# ou
lista += outra_lista
```

Código final:

```
def obtemPalavras(nomeArquivo):
    palavras = []
    with open(nomeArquivo, "r") as arquivo:
        for line in arquivo:
            palavras += line.replace("\n", "").lower().split()

    return palavras
```

---

### Possível problema com memória

Se você montar uma lista com todas as palavras e o seu arquivo for muito grande, seu programa pode gastar muito recurso para manter tudo em memória.

Se você usar [*generators*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) você pode devolver 1 palavra por vez, a medida que for necessário.

Modificando o exemplo anterior para usar *generators* ficaria:

```
def obtemPalavras(nomeArquivo):
    with open(nomeArquivo, "r") as arquivo:
        for line in arquivo:
            for palavra in line.replace("\n", "").lower().split():
                yield palavra
```

Melhorando o exemplo utilizando `yield from`:

```
def obtemPalavras(nomeArquivo):
    with open(nomeArquivo, "r") as arquivo:
        for line in arquivo:
            yield from line.replace("\n", "").lower().split()
```

Agora a função `obtemPalavras` lê o nosso arquivo e retorna uma palavras por vez, e a medida que formos pedindo mais palavras, ela lê o arquivo para buscá-las. Dessa maneira poderíamos abrir um arquivo grande sem medo de estourar a memória do seu computador.

Para exemplificar, imagine que o arquivo `frase.txt` contém o seguinte conteúdo:

```
Uma frase com cinco palavras
Outra frase
Olá mundo
```

Podemos percorrer todas as palavras da seguinte maneira:

```
print("Palavras em 'frases.txt':")
for palavra em obtemPalavras("frases.txt"):
    print("-", palavra)
```

O resultado seria:

```
Palavras em 'frases.txt':
- Uma
- frase
- com
- cinco
- palavras
- Outra
- frase
- Olá
- mundo
```

---

### Tratamento de strings

Você não precisa remover o caractere de nova linha usando `line.replace("\n", "")` pois quando você usa o método [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) sem nenhum parâmetro, o separador utilizado são quaisquer espaços em branco, e como `\n` é um espaço em branco também é removido da lista resultante.

```
"1 2 3 4 5 \n \n".split()
# ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Você também está convertendo seus caracteres para caixa baixa usando [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) para que seu algoritmo seja *case insensitive*, para fins de conhecimento você poderia usar o método [`str.casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) para o mesmo propósito.
Este método também converte para caixa baixa, porém contém tratamento de caracteres especiais que não funcionam com [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) (como o caractere `ß` do alemão, por exemplo).

---

### Conclusão

Seu código final ficaria assim:

```
def is_palindrome(string):
    return string == string[::-1]

def get_words(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as arquivo:
        for linha in arquivo:
            yield from linha.casefold().split()

for palavra in get_words('frases.txt'):
    if is_palindrome(palavra):
        print(palavra)
```

Saída:

```
ama
a
anna
é
o
asa
o
socorrammesubinoonibusemmarrocos
bob
```

<sup>Código rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-413972-6333)</sup>

Espero que tenha sido útil...

Answer (score 1):

Santana, utilizando seu exemplo, fiz algumas alterações para chegar ao resultado que você diz:

- Fechei o arquivo após utilizar o mesmo
- A função obtemPalavras passou a retornar uma lista das palavras encontradas no arquivo, sendo que quebro a lista com base em espaços (split)
- A função palindromo passou a ser chamada no loop da lista de palavras

```
def palindromo(palavra):
  if len(palavra) <= 1:
    return True
  else:
    return palavra[0] == palavra[len(palavra) - 1] and palindromo(palavra[1:len(palavra) - 1])


def obtemPalavras(nomeArquivo):
  arquivo = open(nomeArquivo, "r")
  palavras = ""

  for line in arquivo:
    palavras += line.replace("\n", " ")

  arquivo.close()

  return palavras.lower().split(" ")


nomeArquivo = "palavras.txt"
palavras = obtemPalavras(nomeArquivo)
for palavra in palavras:
  if palindromo(palavra):
    print (palavra)
```

Esse é um exemplo, não se apegue a ele, com Python existem inúmeras formas de escrever esse mesmo código =D